# How could I save large content from Lexical text editor to my database?

Tags: node.js, next.js, lexicaljs

Is there a way that I can save large content from my Lexical editor to my database? Let say the number of words is about 20k.

I tried to serialize the editorState into JSON and JSON stringified string, but when the content exceeds a certain length, the size of the serialized JSON also increases and I'm unable to send it to my backend server. It show "Payload Too Large" error if I do so.

Comment: That's not a problem with your database but rather with your HTTP API. If you need/want to pass such a large JSON object, just increase the limit.

Comment: hi @Bergi, thanks for your response. I think the problem might be because I serialize the whole editorState (which is the whole note) and send it to the server. Therefore if I make a small change on a large content, it will still send large request body, which is costly. Do you have any idea if Lexical has a solution for this? I've searched everywhere but haven't found the solution.

Comment: Oh you mean the https://lexical.dev editor in particular? You can probably try your own JSON diff algorithm on the editor state and pass only that diff to your API in a `PATCH` request

Comment: thanks @Bergi, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Alternatively, try [the html export](https://lexical.dev/docs/concepts/serialization#lexical---html), that might be smaller than the JSON depending on your documents